# Is there a de facto registry for discovering Java libraries?

Tags: java, maven, kotlin, package, package-managers

I grew out of touch with the Java community as I embraced Javascript and node.js for web development. I found myself blown away by the NPM package registry for Javascript tools and libraries. If it's been done, chances are I can find it and even choose from multiple competing implementations. And then in one fell swoop I can `npm install` it to make it available to my project.

I'm now getting back into Java and haven't found anything analogous. My searches for Java libraries have led me all around the net, usually to blog compilations. I've browsed [the maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/) for libraries but have not yet found it helpful. Maven doesn't seem written for discovery, only for enabling downloads and managing dependencies. There is rarely more than a one-line description for any package, whereas NPM makes the github READMEs accessible at a glance, all presented in a consistent way for easy comparison.

Is there a de facto registry for discovering Java libraries? If not, how do people go about finding the libraries you need? Rummaging through Google as I've been doing?

(I'll mainly be developing in Kotlin and would love a way to discover Kotlin solutions too.)

Comment: Even if there was such a registry, you'd end up searching it through Google. Being hand-maintained, it would probably be less up-to-date than general Google's search results. Less informative, too, since you'd just be reading their authors' viewpoint.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: "it would probably be less up-to-date than general Google's search results." I guess that's the beauty of NPM. Because it's the de facto registry for JS, authors regularly `npm publish` to post their latest github README, keeping the registry as up-to-date as devs desire.

Comment: How is NPM at an advantage, though? If you Google for a Kotlin lib, you'll see all the README content through GitHub. My guess is you'd do exactly the same for JS.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: "How is NPM at an advantage, though?" On google we sort through reams of irrelevant results and then try to find the link to the github page, multiply clicking forward and back. On NPM, the relevant results are all in one concise list, one click forward to see docs, one click back to return to the list. Hours of time, possibly failing to find anything, vs minutes of time, finding everything there is to find. See for example: https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=image%20library

Comment: Ah cool, it's more than a registry, it has some scoring system as well.

Comment: I doubt we can have something like this in Java (btw NPM resembles .NET NuGet package management pretty closely). The problem is that if you build your application with Spring Framework, you'd quite often be using Spring-enabled modules. If it is Apache Camel - than you search for Camel-enabled modules, and so on. Every framework typically maintains their list of available modules. Yet when generic functionality is needed like better real number math, the choice is rarely too broad to get confused.

Comment: Basically you are asking to recommend an offsite resource. Which renders the whole topic off topic. It isn't a bad question, it simply doesnt fit here, imho.

Comment: @GhostCat: "Basically you are asking to recommend an offsite resource." Yeah, if there is no de facto registry, then the best people can do is make recommendations, which I do appreciate! Were there a de facto registry, as with NPM and Javascript, there'd be a definitive, objective answer.

Comment: Asking for off site resources makes the question off topic here. Do you understand what that means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are none similar to NPM.

Only mitigation I'm aware of are "awesome" lists:

Kotlin:
https://kotlin.link/

Java:
http://java-lang.github.io/awesome-java/

Comment: Fantastic! These are helpful. Thank you!